# My game objects dont show up when using null

Tags: javascript, java

When I was using absolute layout my objects where appearing but I couldnt move them so I changed the layout to null and now my objects dont even appear. Please help.

Havent tried much, not sure what to try.

```
    try {
        enemies = new LinkedList<>();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

        ActionListener spawnEnemies = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                spawnEnemies();
            }
        };
        ActionListener moveEnemies = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                moveEnemies();
            }
        };

        spawner = new Timer(50000, spawnEnemies);
        spawner.start();
        mover = new Timer(10, moveEnemies);
        mover.start();
        addKeyListener(new KeyInput(this));

        player = new PlayerObj("white", 399, 399, frame);
        player.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        //AddActionEvent, Keylogging, OnbuttonPress, Autogenerating enemies, timers.
        frame.getContentPane().add(player);

        spawnEnemies();

        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Why is this tagged with javascript and java?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you want with the code, but I assume you want to display enemies/players at specified locations on screen. I personally don't decommend using Components added to a JFrame to display that. This means with no layout, the JFrame will have no idea how to place these objects.

Here is an other way that will solve your problem, howewer it is a totally different approach.

You have to create a JFrame, and set its content pane to a new JPanel(recommended to extend your class from JPanel and adding itself to the JFrame, it can make things easier).
Then, you override the repaint method, by creating the following:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
}
```

When you call the repaint() method, it will run this code. So inside here, you can paint whatewer and wherever you want (inside you JPanel). And you don't have to mess with the Layout, just leave it as default.

Examples for painting:

```
g.setColor(Color.blue);
g.fillRect(50,50,120,120);
//
g.drawImage(yourImage,100,100,this);
```